# Math opportunities for a graduate

Tags: soft-question

Are there any opportunities for young mathematicians who have finished their undergraduate education and are taking a year before going to graduate school, but want to do something math related? To make it even more specific, opportunities in Europe?

I have looked around online, but everything seems to be for undergraduates or graduates who are in a program.

Edit: I am particularly looking for opportunities that would provide financial aid.

Comment: What do you mean by opportunity? As in courses at an university, that are not in a program? Or jobs? Or volountering? As for coursework, Swedish universities,for example, offer a lot of free-standing courses.